# PostgreSQL: Do I need to return anything in a CTE?

Tags: postgresql, return

I once heard that a CTE (WITH statement) needs to have returning something. Otherwise it might happen that it will not be executed.

I have following CTE simplified structure:

```
WITH
selectA AS (
    SELECT ...
),
insertA AS (
    INSERT INTO ...
    -- selecting something from selectA
    RETURNING ...
),
insertB AS (
    INSERT INTO ... 
    -- selecting something from selectA and insertA
    -- HERE no RETURNING!
),
selectB AS (
    SELECT ...
    -- selecting something from selectA and insertA
),
insertForms AS (
    INSERT INTO ...
    -- selecting something from selectB
    -- HERE no RETURNING!
),
insertFormData AS (
    INSERT INTO ...
    -- selecting something from selectB
    -- HERE no RETURNING!
)
SELECT ...
    -- selecting something from insertA and selectB
```

It works but I am wondering if I hit any corner case causing that all CTE parts get executed.
In the PostgreSQL documentation I did not find a clear hint if a returning part is necessary within a CTE.

Does anyone have a good thought for that?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*but I am wondering if I hit any corner case*" - that behaviour is fully documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#sql-with)

> If RETURNING is omitted, the statement is still executed, but it produces no output so it cannot be referenced as a table by the primary query

Comment: Thanks a lot. How could I miss that